# System.Data.SqLite DataProvider not found when executing Test using NUnit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nunit, system.data.sqlite

I am facing a problem with my UnitTest. I want to Test my Data-Access which is done using a repository based on NPoco. I have therefore written a couple of tests and the test project retrieves NUnit, NPoco, System.Data.SQLite, and some other Stuff via NuGet.

This is the app.config of the TestProject:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="RepositoryTests.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=db.sqlite;Version=3" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
     </system.data>
</configuration>
```

In VS, the Project builds fine. Triggering the tests in Visual Studio works as well.

Building the Projects with MSBUILD works as well. Running the tests via nunit after building them with msbuild.exe raises a Exception though:

`Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.`

This is only the case, when executing the tests using nunit directly (sth. like `nunit-console.exe myproject.csproj /config:Release`). Triggering them in VS is no problem.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the nunit test runner having its own app.config in which your settings are not present.

The simplest way to solve the problem is to move the configuration out of your app.config and into the code itself. Whatever you have in app.config can be done inside code.

Another solution is to move the configuration into a seperate file and then explicitly load that file's configuration using code. Just make sure that the file is copied to the output folder on build.

You could use something like:

```
public static class TestFactory
{
    public static DatabaseFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

    public static void Setup()
    {
        var fluentConfig = FluentMappingConfiguration.Configure(new OurMappings());
        //or individual mappings
        //var fluentConfig = FluentMappingConfiguration.Configure(new UserMapping(), ....);

        DbFactory = DatabaseFactory.Config(x =>
        {
            // Load the connection string here or just use a constant in code...
            x.UsingDatabase(() => new Database("connString");
            x.WithFluentConfig(fluentConfig);
            x.WithMapper(new Mapper());
        });
    }
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/wiki/Fluent-mappings-including-conventional) for more details.

Then in the test fixture:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DbTestFixture
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        TestFactory.Setup();
    }

    [Test]
    public void YourTestHere()
    {
        var database = TestFactory.DbFactory.GetDatabase();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your provided code unfortunately didn't do the trick. I'll vote it up though, because the hint with the nunit-config-file-problem finally let to a (hacky) solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by creating an copy of the `app.config`-file and give that copy the name of the Test-Project, followed by `.config`. So if we assume, that the project is named **Test.Project** the copy must be named **Test.Project.config**. Nunit doesn't seem to load the automatically generated *Test.Project.dll.config*. This info can be found somewhat disguised in the [NUnit-docs](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=configFiles&r=2.6.4) (Configuration Files -> Test Configuration File -> 3rd paragraph, last sentence).

In VS, in the Properties-Section of that copied file, i set the copy-to-output-directory-property to `always`.

Executing the tests with `nunit-console.exe` then lead to another exception (`Bad-Image`), which was caused by NUnit not finding the **SQLite.Interop.dll**-file. This could be solved kind of hacky by adding that file, which already resides in the `x64` or `x86` folder, as an existing element to the solution in VS and also setting the copy-to-output-dir-property to `always`.